# draw on transparent window using pen

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I want to draw on a transparent window using a pen.

When drawing a line black area surround the line.

This image shows the problem:

[image]

How to solve this problem?

```
LRESULT __stdcall WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT iMessage, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hdc, backDC;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    static Point prevPt;

    // Draw or Erase
    static bool isDraw = false;
    static bool isErase = false;

    // Select Pen Color
    static int selectColor = 1;

    // Color Pen(R, G, B) and Current Pen
    static HPEN redPen;
    static HPEN greenPen;
    static HPEN bluePen;
    static HPEN* currentPen = &redPen;

    switch (iMessage)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        redPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 4, RGB(255, 0, 0));
        greenPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 4, RGB(0, 255, 0));
        bluePen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 4, RGB(0, 0, 255));
        return 0L;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        cout << "\n" << "destroying window" << endl;
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0L;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        return 0L;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        prevPt.x = LOWORD(lParam);
        prevPt.y = HIWORD(lParam);
        isDraw = true;
        return 0L;
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        isDraw = false;
        return 0L;
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    {
        int x = LOWORD(lParam);
        int y = HIWORD(lParam);
        if (isDraw)
        {
            hdc = GetDC(g_hWnd);

            HPEN OldPen = (HPEN)SelectObject(hdc, *currentPen);
            MoveToEx(hdc, prevPt.x, prevPt.y, NULL);
            LineTo(hdc, x, y);

            prevPt.x = x;
            prevPt.y = y;
            DeleteObject(OldPen);
            ReleaseDC(g_hWnd, hdc);
        }
    }
    return 0L;
    case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
        isErase = true;
        return 0L;
    case WM_RBUTTONUP:
        isErase = false;
        return 0L;
    case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
        if (selectColor > 3)
            selectColor = 1;

        if (selectColor == 1)   // Red
            currentPen = &redPen;
        else if (selectColor == 2)
            currentPen = &greenPen;
        else if (selectColor == 3)
            currentPen = &bluePen;

        selectColor++;
        return 0L;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, iMessage, wParam, lParam);
}

void main()
{
    HWND window;
    LPCWSTR myclass = L"DrawTest";

    WNDCLASSEX wndclass = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW, WindowProc,
    0, 0, NULL, LoadIcon(0,IDI_APPLICATION), LoadCursor(0,IDC_ARROW), (HBRUSH)WHITE_BRUSH, 0, myclass, LoadIcon(0,IDI_APPLICATION) };
    if (RegisterClassEx(&wndclass))
    {
        window = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, myclass, L"title", WS_POPUP, 0, 0, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFULLSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFULLSCREEN), 0, 0, NULL, 0);
    }

    VideoCapture* pCapture = nullptr;
    pCapture = new VideoCapture(0);

    if (pCapture)
    {
        if (!pCapture->isOpened())
        {
            cout << "Can not open video file." << endl;
            return;
        }

        int fps = (int)(pCapture->get(CAP_PROP_FPS));

        int delay = 0;
        if (fps == 0)
            fps = 24;

        delay = 1000 / fps;

        Mat colorMat;

        while (1)
        {
            *pCapture >> colorMat;
            if (colorMat.empty())
                break;

            Mat copyColor;
            colorMat.copyTo(copyColor);

            imshow("colorMat", copyColor);

            int ckey = waitKey(delay);
            if (ckey == 27)
                break;

            if (window)
            {
                ShowWindow(window, SW_SHOW);
                MSG msg;
                if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE))
                {
                    GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0);
                    TranslateMessage(&msg);
                    DispatchMessage(&msg);
                }
            }
        }

        cv::destroyAllWindows();
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you make the window transparent?

Comment: I think it would be useful to provide a screenshot of the "black pixels around the line" that you are describing.

Comment: I declare WNDCLASSEX structure and use CreateWindowEx() function. I assign 'WS_EX_TRANSPARENT' option in this function's first parameter.

Comment: I already provided screenshot. it is linked 'enter image description here' below the code I attached.

Comment: Setting only *WS_EX_TRANSPARENT* doesnt make the window transparent. You need to set *WS_EX_LAYERED* also and set in the end the opacity with **SetLayeredWindowAttributes**. What is the complete code in *WinMain()*? Also with *WS_EX_TRANSPARENT* you **DONT** get any mouse messages! How do you draw?

Comment: I edit this post. I attach entire code block.
I create console project and use WINAPI for creating transparent window.

Comment: You are not supposed to delete `OldPen`. You are supposed to select it back into the DC before releasing it. Also you'd probably be better off doing all your drawing in `WM_PAINT`, using `InvalidateRect()` to queue a redraw in `WM_MOUSEMOVE`.

Comment: The *WS_EX_TRANSPARENT* message doesnt have anything to do with transparency! It just stops registering mouse messages. So it is realy strange how did you achieve transparency with your code. The way to get transparency is with *WS_EX_LAYERED * style and setting a color for complete transparency with **SetLayeredWindowAttributes**

Comment: @andlabs. I did the way you are suggested. But it does not draw line. Just dots. So I try to find another way.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε. I tried to use **SetLayerdWindowAttributes** function and I did. But when I draw a line, the window as well as the line were transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, create a layered window:

```
window = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED, myclass, L"title", WS_POPUP, 0, 0,
                        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFULLSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFULLSCREEN),
                        HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

set color transparency the same as your background brush:

```
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(window, RGB(255, 255, 255), 0, LWA_COLORKEY);
```

In *WM_PAINT*

```
hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

HPEN OldPen = (HPEN)SelectObject(hdc, *currentPen);

//set random values
MoveToEx(hdc, 50, 50, NULL);
LineTo(hdc, 450, 450);

SelectObject(hdc, OldPen);

EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

return 0;
```

This code works, **BUT** you cant get mouse messages cause the window is transparent. That is the main issue, not the drawing.

**EDIT**

The problem is how to get mouse messages. The solution is to create a second window on top of your main window with opacity *nearly* zero so it is not visible but get the mouse messages!

```
window = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED, myclass, L"title", WS_POPUP, 0, 0,
                        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFULLSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFULLSCREEN),
                        HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, NULL, NULL);

windowClone = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED, myclass, L"title", WS_POPUP, 0, 0,
                        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFULLSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFULLSCREEN),
                        window, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Make your main window complete transparent:

```
//background color MUST be the same with color Key!
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(window, RGB(255, 255, 255), 0, LWA_COLORKEY);
```

Make nearly transparent your clone window

```
//The transparency is set to 1
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(windowClone, 0, 1, LWA_ALPHA);

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    static int draw = FALSE, startX, startY, endX, endY, posX, posY;


    switch(message){ //handle the messages 
        case WM_PAINT:
            printf("WM_PAINT \n");

            if( hwnd == window && draw == TRUE ){
                HPEN OldPen, redPen;

                redPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 4, RGB(255, 0, 0));

                hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

                OldPen = (HPEN)SelectObject(hdc, redPen);

                MoveToEx(hdc, startX, startY, NULL);
                LineTo(hdc, endX, endY);

                SelectObject(hdc, OldPen);

                EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

                DeleteObject(redPen);

                return 0;
            }

            break;

        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
            //printf("WM_MOUSEMOVE \n");

            if( hwnd == windowClone && draw == TRUE ){
                startX = posX;
                startY = posY;
                endX = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
                endY = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);

                posX = endX;
                posY = endY;

                InvalidateRect(window, NULL, FALSE);
            }

            break;

        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            printf("WM_LBUTTONDOWN \n");

            if( hwnd == windowClone ){
                posX = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
                posY = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
                draw = TRUE;
            }

            break;

       case WM_LBUTTONUP:
           printf("WM_LBUTTONUP \n");

           if( hwnd == windowClone && draw == TRUE ){
               draw = FALSE;
           }

           break;

       case WM_CAPTURECHANGED:
           printf("WM_CAPTURECHANGED \n");

           if( hwnd == windowClone && draw == TRUE ){
               draw = FALSE;
           }

           break;

        default:   //for messages that we don't deal with
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to draw lines, circles and so on by mouse event. But your opinion is the drawing on transparent window by mouse event is impossible. Is it?

Comment: @EthanYoung-JaePark You can but with a little trick. See edit

Comment: Thank you. I thought the way you suggested and applied my project. Then, It works very well. Thank you XD